# Extra Sanitisation When Dealing With Fetched Data

Tags: php, security, prepared-statement, sanitization

I have some data being fetched from a database (that is sanitised on the way in to the database with a prepared statement). When using this data I thought I'd have to use the htmlspecialchars() function, but having used a password which contained special characters this broke the code because it obviously turned the `<` into an html entity.

Am I correct in thinking if the code is sanitised going into the database, and isn't being physically outputted on to the html page, I don't have to add any extra security to what I have below?

I initially wrapped the code inside the `while` loop in the htmlspecialchars() e.g. `$db_id = htmlspecialchars($row['ID']);` which is how I found it was breaking the code.

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? ");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email );

    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    // assign columns from the database to variables
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

       $db_id = $row['ID'];
       $db_firstname = $row['firstname'];
       $db_email = $row['email'];
       $db_password = $row['password'];

    }

    $stmt->close();
    $connection->close();

    // code will go here that checks if the email and password match and then create a $_SESSION

}
```

Comment: SQL and XSS injections are different issues. You need different solutions for each `htmlspecialchars` will prevent XSS injection. Use it only for outputting. You shouldn't ever have to output a password, and if you did it should be gibberish because it was hashed.

Comment: hi @user3783243 that is what I thought. I wanted to ask for confirmation because I'm new to PHP. Thanks for taking the time to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is correct and safe. You don't need anything else.

There is no such thing as input sanitization. **Prepared statements do not sanitize data**. They protect against SQL injection because the data is sent separately from the query.

`htmlspecialchars()` protects against XSS. You use it **when you output the data into HTML**. Do not use it on input as it will damage your data.

**Never modify passwords in any way!**. Use `password_hash()` directly on the input and save that into the database.